# Amazon Reporting API Not Working ? (Website Temporarily Unavailable?)

Tags: python-3.x, reporting, jupyter-lab

I am trying to connect to the Amazon reporting API but am getting an error saying the website is currently unavailable. Has anyone successfully used this API?

My code is down below but this is the error that I get:

```html
Error: 403 - <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Website Temporarily Unavailable</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<center><img src="http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/website/errors/503/generic.png" alt="website temporarily unavailable" width="500" height="300"></center>
</body>

</html>
```

**Below is the code that I wrote:**

```py
import requests

# Define the URL for the Amazon Reporting API endpoint you want to call
reporting_api_url = 'https://api.amazon.com/marketplacecommerceanalytics/2022-01-01/reports'  # Replace with your desired endpoint

# Define your access token obtained from the LWA Access Token request
access_token = 'your access token (hidden on git question)'  # Replace with your actual access token

# Define the headers for the request, including the Authorization header
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    # Add any other required headers here
}

try:
    # Make an HTTP GET request to the Amazon Reporting API with the Authorization header
    response = requests.get(reporting_api_url, headers=headers)

    # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Parse and process the response data as needed
        data = response.json()
        print("Response Data:")
        print(data)
    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
```